# When is $m! > \binom{n}{m}$?

Tags: asymptotics, binomial-coefficients, intuition, factorial

Given $n$ a postive integer, when is $m! > \binom{n}{m}$?  I'm looking for an upper bounds on the value of $m$, as a function of $n$, with a formula that hopefully doesn't contain any special functions.  Hopefully there is a good upper bounds that meets these criteria!

Comment: @AlexR.:  No I haven't.  I did find an (experimental) upper bounds of roughly $(10^{1/2})n^{1/2}$, or, slightly better, $(10^{1/2 \cdot 0.98})n^{1/2 \cdot 0.98}$, where the $0.98$ can be adjusted somewhat.  I just wasn't sure how to derive a formula using $n$.  Plus, this formula is based on plugging in values into math software.

Comment: All I know to suggest is Stirling's formula.

Comment: @TedShifrin:  I tried plugging in Stirling's formula into Mathematica, and it couldn't solve it.  I will keep playing around with it to see if I can somehow find an answer...

Answer (score 3):

From [Wikipedia's Factorial page->Rate of growth and approximations for large $n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Rate_of_growth_and_approximations_for_large_n), we have:

$$\tag{1} e \left( \frac{m}{e} \right)^m \le m!$$

...and if we do some simple math:

$$\binom{n}{m} = \frac{n!}{(n-m)!} \frac{1}{m!} \le n^m \frac{1}{m!}$$

Then, plugging in $(1)$ for $m!$:

$$n^m \left( \frac{1}{m!} \right) \le n^m \left( \frac{(e/m)^m}{e} \right) = \frac{(e \cdot n)^m}{e \cdot m^m}$$

...which gives us:

$$\tag{2} \binom{n}{m} \le \frac{(e \cdot n)^m}{e \cdot m^m} \le e \left( \frac{m}{e} \right)^m \le m!$$

So we'd like to find the smallest $m$ such that:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{(e \cdot n)^m}{e \cdot m^m} &\le e \left( \frac{m}{e} \right)^m\\
\frac{e^{2m}n^m}{e \cdot m^{2m}} &\le e \\
\frac{e^{2m}n^m}{m^{2m}} &\le e^2 \\
\left( \frac{e \sqrt{n}}{m} \right)^{2m} &\le e^2 \\
\frac{e \sqrt{n}}{m} &\le e^{1/m} \\
e \sqrt{n} &\le m \cdot e^{1/m}
\end{align}$$

This is *almost* the "Lambert $W$ function", or "omega function" of $\sqrt{n}$, which has fairly sizable entries in [Wikipedia's page on it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) and [Wolfram's page on it](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html), among other locations.

According to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=m+E%5E(1%2Fm)%3D%3Dc), the corresponding solution, when there is equality, is:

$$m = - \frac{1}{W{\left( -\frac{1}{e \sqrt{n}} \right) }}$$

Comment: By taking floor and ceiling approximations of $\int_1^n \ln x ~dx$, it can be shown that $n^n e^{1 - n} \le n! \le  n^{n+1} e^{1 - n}$, the first half of which is equivalent to your inequality (1).